# Angular: Got error on using viewchild with form of ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dirty' of undefined

Tags: angular

I am trying to get the form element using viewchild in angular 5 app as illustrated below, but got error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' (pointing to this.campaignForm.form) of undefined.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'form-child',
  template: 
    `<div ngif="show">
      <form #campaignForm="ngForm">
        <input type="text" [ngModel]='data.input' (ngModelChange)='updateMe()' name='input' required/>
      </form>
    </div>
 `
})
export class FormChild implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChange {
  @Input() data: any;
  @Output() valid = new EventEmitter();
  @ViewChild('campaignForm') campaignForm: NgForm;

  show = true;

  constructor() {
    // console.log('here1');
  }

  updateMe() {
    console.log('update me: ', this.campaignForm.form.valid);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.campaignForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
      this.valid.emit(this.campaignForm.form.valid);
    }

  }  
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App, FormChild ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Try changing the `valueChanges` subscription from `ngOnInit` to `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: That does not work, I was thinking maybe angular 5 does not support this anymore.

Comment: `[ngModel]='data.input'`.  Your binding is for `data.input`, but you haven't initialized `data` anywhere, are you sure it's correct?

Comment: Actually, this is just a related code...moreover that is not the problem. The problem is getting undefined on even campaignForm itself.

Comment: It's working, see [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-form-0x23)

Comment: So what I am missing in my own?

Comment: the post has been updated...the `ngif` obscures the form, so until @viewchildren is used it is not accessible. The problem I now get is that my valid property is returning undefine.